# How to access a ModelAndView object added without attribute name within the jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, modelandview

I was going through spring MVC tutorials and came across ModelAndView.

My JSP view looks like this,

```
<%@taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix = "form"%>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Spring MVC </title>
   </head>
   <body>

      <h2>Submitted Student Information</h2>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>${student.getName()}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>${student.getAge()}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>${student.getBranch()}</td>
         </tr>
      </table>  
   </body>
</html>
```

It worked when I set both attribute name and attribute value in controller like the following,

```
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("result");
        Student student = new Student("arun2", "CSE", 22);
        mv.addObject("student",student);
        return mv;
```

Then I came across other overloaded method `ModelAndView.addObject(Object attributeValue)`  and I tried setting only attribute value `mv.addObject(student);` But this time it doesn't show student details in the browser.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to access those values in JSP by just setting attribute value as i did second-time `mv.addObject(student);`.
2. If yes, How? If not, Why do we have such overloaded method? Why do we need to set only value if we can't access it in the view (JSP)?

I went through the javadocs, But didn't find anything that could make me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like that and access the parameters,but need to pay some attention.

Check the API for addObject at **[ModelAndView](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html)**,it will shows method as below:
[image]

Then,let's look at the definition of **[ModelMap.addAttribute(Object)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html#addAttribute-java.lang.Object-)**
[image]

It shows ***using a [generated name](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Conventions.html#getVariableName-java.lang.Object-)***,the definition of **generated name** listed as below:
[image]

So,if you just want to use the `mv.addObject(student)` method,you can access data in your jsp page as below:

```
<%@taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix = "form"%>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Spring MVC </title>
   </head>
   <body>

      <h2>Submitted Student Information</h2>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>${student.name}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>${student.age}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>${student.branch}</td>
         </tr>
      </table>  
   </body>
</html>
```

If the object is a `Group` class, then you can get value via `${group.name}`

And pay attention that the **ModelAndView** is from **org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView**

Also,I suggest you use the **[EL Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaim.html)** to access data in your jsp page directly.

Comment: But what if I add multiple attributes of the same class? Is it allowed? say I added two attributes  `student1` `student2` of class  `Student`.What now?

Comment: I just tested add one object of same class yesterday and it worked, you can try it youself,maybe there would be some exception

Comment: I tried too. It only works the way you have explained it. If we set 2 objects `student1` and `student2`of same class `Student`, It only takes the first object we set in the controller.

Comment: That's weird,in most case the latter one will override the previous one

Comment: I thought the same! But that's how it worked when I tested.